# What goes into tom yum soup?

Tags: soup, thai-cuisine

I've bought some tom yum paste. The label says 2 tbsp per cup of water, **add meats and vegetables as preferred**.

What would be good, reasonably authentic solids?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_yum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard would be shrimp, mushrooms, and green onions.

Possibly some hot peppers, but if the paste is sufficiently spicy, you might want to use a more mild pepper for texture